# Which better serialization,deserialization OR static object

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I want to keep track user data on android application store on `User` object, And i want to know from performance,memory aspects  which is better.

1- Serialize `User` object, Then deserialize user object each time i need.

```
    public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object)
        throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context
            .openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object object = ois.readObject();
        return object;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

- IS `serialization,deserialization` hit performance ?

If yes, So using Static object to keep track user data throw all application will be better, Or there is **another** preferred method to keep track user data throw all android application.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in android it's better to use Parcelable than Serialization

Don't use static objects unless your sure you're gonna be able to maintain it and not let them hangout in the memory more than they should

If the object is simple and not too large just pass it as parcelable .. if it's too big , save it locally in a database of file or something then load it wherever you wanna use it

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is for saving state of an object on disk. And is useful in many scenarios. 
Let's take simple example, a game, you play game, clear 3rd level, closed it and when you start again it starts from 3rd level.

This can not be achieved with static objects. Because when game is closed, JVM exits, and static objects will loose values.

Here serialization comes in picture, when game starts values are read and assigned back.

Now if your application does not use this feature, go for static objects, becuase serialization/dfeserialization does hit performance.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the serialization,deserialization you will be restricting your application to add new data to be stored for User information. You should save user information in defined format to avoid this problem.

Also, your application will be used only by single user at a time, so considering the performance issue is worth only to read the previous user.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization and deserialization is too slow. If you can maintain the information in static objects, this is the better way. Use serialization only if you need to save data when application is closed.

Additionally, you can use Shared Preferences to save some simple dictionary data.